# Python build failed

Tags: python, build, makefile

I was trying to build python from source. Durring

> $make test

this error arose and caused the build to fail.

> ====================================================================== ERROR: test_idna (test.test_socket.GeneralModuleTests)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/h/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Lib/test/test_socket.py", line 1287,
>   in test_idna
>       socket.gethostbyname('испытание.python.org') socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 506 tests in 150.098s
>
> FAILED (errors=1, skipped=24) test test_socket failed make: *** [test]
>   Error 1

Im sketched by having the russian URL in the source of python. Was python hacked?
what is this?  It translates into ispytanie.python.org
but i still have no clue why its there.

UPDATE:
http://ispytanie.python.org/
the page which was the translation, of the Russian page, no longer works.
anyone who follows the directions for a Linux install, running $make test
will likely encounter this error.

Comment: It's probably either testing unicode support in gethostbyname ?? or it's assuming that there's such a server always up so that test will always pass (there currently isn't as far as I can see).  Try fiddling with the code.. e.g. first try "www.python.org" cause that's up.  Then try some unicode host see if that works.  It'll give you a bit more info.

Answer (score 5):

I edited Python-3.4.2/Lib/test/test_socket.py and removed 3 instances of Russian URLs, replacing them with 'python.org' which now allows for $make test to succeed.